# Merge onkeydown functions

Tags: javascript, function, javascript-objects, dom-events, onkeydown

I'm trying to merge twice "onkeydown" function due to it's does not working together. Code is below:

## FUNCTION - 1

```
document.onkeydown = checkKeycode
function checkKeycode(e) {
  var event = e || window.event;
  var keycode = event.which || event.keyCode;

  if (keycode == 91) {
     alert("Windows");
  }
}
```

## FUNCTION - 2

```
document.onkeydown = function(e){
var n = (window.Event) ? e.which : e.keyCode;
if(n==116 || n==27 || n==112 || n==123 || n==17) return false;
}

var keys = {};

 $(document).keydown(function (e) {
  keys[e.which] = true;
 });

 $(document).keyup(function (e) {
   delete keys[e.which];
});
```

When the page running Function - 1 isn't working.

Comment: Why are you using two handlers for the same event? This makes things more complicated than it usually can be.

Answer (score 1):

You can only have one `onkeydown` method. To make it work, you should use eventListener, for instance:

```
document.addEventListener('keyDown', checkKeycode);
```

You can then add your second function and it will work

Answer (score 1):

This won't work since 2nd function overwrites the first function.

Example:

```
var d;
d = 1;
d = 2;
console.log(d); // prints '2'

var c;
c = () => { return '1'; }; 
c = () => { return '2'; };
console.log(c()); // prints '2'
```

These are JavaScript fundamentals.

If you want to listen for `onkeydown` event you should use `EventListeners` and fire your functions on event like:

```
document.addEventListener('keyDown', function1);
document.addEventListener('keyDown', function2);
// both function will execute on keyDown event
```